# Each subset of the natural numbers is finite or countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Proposition**:

Each subset of the natural numbers is finite or countable.

**Proof**:

Let $X \subset \omega$.

First case: $X$ is bounded. That means that $(\exists k \in \omega)(\forall y \in X) y \leq k$. Then $X \subset k+1$ and $X$, as a subset of a finite subset, is  finite .

Second case: $X$ is not bounded, i.e. $(\forall k \in \omega) (\exists y \in X) k<y$.
Then for all $k \in \omega$, $\min(X-(k+1))$ is defined. We define the recursively the function $f: \omega \to X$ 
$$ f(0)= \text{ the smallest element of }X=\min X\\f(n+1)=\text{the smallest element of X that is greater than } f(n)=\min \{ X-(f(n)+1)\}$$

From the definition of $f$ we have that $f(n+1)>f(n)$
, i.e. $f$ is strictly increasing and so $1-1$.
It suffices to show that $f$ is injective.

Could you explain me how we conclude that for all $k \in \omega$, $\min (X-(k+1))$ is defined?

Also at the definition of $f(n+1)$ why do we add $1$ to $f(n)$ ?

Comment: From wikipedia: "a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers"

Comment: I have understood the definition of a countable set. My questions are at the two last lines. @ModdedBear

Comment: I don't understand the point of proving a subset of $\mathbb N$ has the same cardinality as a subset of $\mathbb N$ or is finite.

Comment: The point of @ModdedBear 's comment is that the proof depends on the definition you are using. Here you can use the definition by showing that each subset of $\mathbb N$ has the same cardinality as itself, which is trivial. So if that won't do, what definition are you working to?

Comment: Note also that "countable" is sometimes ambiguous. I always include finite sets as countable, but others use the word to imply countably infinite (as appears to be the case in your question).

Comment: That's the definition I am using:
$$$$
A set is called countable if it is equinumerous with the set of natural numbers $\omega$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I mean that it should be countably infinite.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, $X-k$ is the set $X\setminus \{0,1,\ldots,k\}$, so $\min(X-(k+1))$ is the minimum element on $X$ without considering $0,\ldots,k+1$.

$f$ is well defined because, since $X$ is unbounded, $X-(k+1)$ is non-empty for every $k$.

In the definition of $f(n+1)$, you  add $1$ to $f(n)$ to guarantee that $f$ is strictly increasing, i.e., you remove the possibility of $f(n)$ being the minimum.

Comment: Is the definition mentioned by the OP  $ f(n+1)$ = min {X-(f(n) + 1)} right ? I do not think that this is the smallest element of X that is greater than $f(n)$. I think that instead of the " + " sign we need " - " sign.

Comment: what about the proof that $f$ is surjective, is not this required to show that X is countable?

Comment: I think that the third line from below in the OP question should be it suffices to show that $f$ is surjective .... right?

Comment: OP asked two questions in particular, I thought it would be off-topic to touch on further properties of $f$.

Comment: you can answer @Intuition in the comments, it is not necessary to edit your answer..... just a suggestion.